# Error: Could not delete data: You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'WHERE ProductsID = 30' Any ideas?

Tags: php

I am trying to delete data from mysql database. But when I view the code I am getting the following error Could not delete data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ProductsID = 30' at line 1

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Delete a Record from MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?--Code to delete-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$dbhost = 'DatabaseHostName';
$dbuser = 'username';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )

{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$ProductsID = $_POST['ProductsID'];

$sql = "DELETE Products ".
       "WHERE ProductsID = $ProductsID" ;

mysql_select_db('dbname');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td width="100">Products ID</td>
    <td><input name="ProductsID" type="text" id="ProductsID"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="100"> </td>
    <td> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="100"> </td>
<td>
    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [DELETE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html). The error message is very clear. You didn't need to post 100 lines of irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, you are missing 'from' change it to this

```
"DELETE from Products WHERE ProductsID = '$ProductsID'" ;
```

Comment: You don't need quotes here as it's not a string id :)

Comment: That's fine but it is a safer way of executing sql isn't it :)